# Doctrine table class inheritance when one subclass has no extra attributes

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I'm having a problem with my mapping. I can't get it to work. I have an abstract base class like so:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="actions")
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"FOO" = "FooAction", "BAR" = "BarAction", ...})
 */
abstract class AbstractAction
{
    ...
}
```

I have a bunch of different actions, all with different fields. E.g:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="actions_foo")
 */
class FooAction extends AbstractAction
{
   ...
}
```

But one of my actions (`BarAction`) does not need any extra fields besides those supplied by the `AbstractAction`. But how can I map that? I tried omitting the `@Table`, or using the same `@Table` as the `AbstractAction`, but to no effect.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="actions")
 */
class BarAction extends AbstractAction
{
   ...
}
```

Omitting the `@Table` gives me a `PDOException` about a missing table `BarAction`. Using the `@Table` of the base class gives me:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

So, how do I map this?

**Edit:** So far I have tried two more things.

I tried removing the `@Entity` as well as the `@Table` from `BarAction` in the hope that this way it would no longer require a database table. That doesn't work. Instead, I get this error:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Class BarAction is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Next I tried creating an `actions_bar` table in my database with just a single foreign key column `id`. Then I mapped the `BarAction` to it. That works (yay!) but it feels crufty and ugly to have an extra SQL table that I don't need at all.

So, still looking for a better way...

Comment: Based on my 2 years experience with D2 and documentation: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance you can go only with one type of inheritance. Either you select joined table inheritance and have a separate table for each entity or select a single table inheritance and have all your entities in one table.

Comment: ased on my 2 years experience with D2 and this [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance), you can go only with one type of inheritance. Either you select joined table inheritance and have a separate table for each entity or select a single table inheritance and have all your entities in one table. (comment added for WizardZ who doesn't have the rep for commenting yet)

Comment: @Sander: Should your `BarAction` really be a subclass of `AbstractAction`? I don't know if it makes sense in your domain model to have `BarAction` as the root of the hierarchy, but from an implementation point of view, that would solve your problem, as `BarAction` would only use the fields from the base table!

Comment: In my domain model it wouldn't make sense to have BarAction as the root. I'm just going to live with the extra SQL table.

Comment: @Garry Lachman: They have no constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `joined` inheritance model (class table inheritance), which uses a separate table for parent and each child. If you don't specify any fields in the child class, Doctrine will just create a table only containing ID field.

And a parent class can only use one type of inheritance, either class table inheritance or single table inheritance.

In that case, if you don't want to have a table with only id column in it, you need to change your data model.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help or add something new. It is not a how to answer but simply taking about concepts.

If you think on classes and you understand your model as: AbstractAction, FooAction and BarAction it is probably because you can have the same methods implemented in a different way on the subclasses or extending some parent method.

If you choose to represent these classes with tables and you choose the "all in one table with a discriminator attribute" i think you have no problem. For the BarAction you will have register with discriminator="BarAction" which will be reprsented by a BarAction.php entity class.

On the other hand if you opt for using different table I consider you need one table per "class". The table for BarAction will only containd the ID field for the AbstractAction but its is required to "classify" (or discriminate) your data as a FooAction.

In summary, I think three tables representing three classes are a fine solution, although the BarAction table simply contains a "link" to the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have to create manually the table in your database.

I have pretty much the same structure an I let Doctrine (2.3) do the job. You have to put @Entity et @Table on each subclasses though.
The error
    Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
may not be related. It could be a cache problem, have you tried flushing it?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem, but I just added some dummy properties into my inherited entity, thinking it can be useful any time. I know its not the perfect idea, but it helped me keep my data model intact and give me the possibility to have own properties in the inherited entities in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late response but it may be useful for others asking this question.

Make the class 'AbstractAction' concrete and add a mapping for it in the discriminator map (You probably want to rename it at this point)

```
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"ABSTRACT" = "AbstractAction", "FOO" = "FooAction", "BAR" = "BarAction", ...})
 */
class AbstractAction
{
```

You should then use that table for rows which need no additional columns