# Incomplete specialization with Doctrine2's Class Table Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-orm

I want to represent files in a database and store metadata depending on whether it's an audio file, a video file or an image file.

The normalized way to deal with this would be multiple tables, each having only the columns needed for the specific file type. The root/superclass table would hold information common to all files (path, name, size, dates, etc).

**Problem:**
Besides the "categorizable" files listed above, there'll always be files I won't provide further metadata for. Hence, all that needs to go into the database is the entry in the root/superclass table.

Having read the [Doctrine 2 Documentation on Class Table Inheritance (CTI)](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), I believe Doctrine2 will not allow objects that are not further specialized:

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity [..]

Is there a way to accomplish this? Why is it not possible?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037882/doctrine-table-class-inheritance-when-one-subclass-has-no-extra-attributes/9750756#9750756` states that one would create another subclass without adding any properties. Doctrine2 would then create a table with a single column: `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around Doctrine in this case, since I wanted to accomplish not only incomplete specialization but also multiple inheritance.

Multiple inheritance: I wanted some files to be both, audio_file and video_file.

In a Doctrine scenario, I imagine one would have had to specify each possible leaf combination as a class. As stated in my comment, even the unspecialized case would have needed to be a class distinct from the root class.

So, what I'm doing is manual SQL queries and building the objects myself. Basically, taking over the part of the ORM in this case. This allows me to stay true to my original database schema.